# SQL - remove last character(s)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to remove the last character of a string if it is a '/' and the string could have multiple '/'s on the end.

For example, I have:

- a/string
- b/string1/
- c/string2//

And want to get:

- a/string
- b/string1
- c/string2

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Which database are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`REPLACE` is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT REPLACE(col1, '/', '') FROM...
```

You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Comment: The OP was looking for replacing the `/` when it's the last character of a string, this will remove all regardless of positioning.

Comment: Yes, when I initially answered this, the OP had put an example that represented wanting `/` removed wherever in the string... The OP has since changed around the question. @AnthonyForloney

Comment: Given his expected input and output, it seems that he still wishes to remove only the `/` at the end of the string.

Comment: Yup - like I said, the original question (before the edit) stated he wished to remove the `/` everywhere in the string. I answered before the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Replace() function [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)
EX

```
replace(string1, '/','')
```

it will remove all of those '/' signs

Comment: OP only wants to remove the last slash, rather than all slashes

Comment: That isn't what was described when I answered the question, his example only contained the end slashes. My answer doesn't fit now, but it did the way he originally asked the question.

Comment: No problem, thank you. 
Im thinking of trying a case system identifying the last instances of the string and cutting them off if it contains a '/' im testing my idea right now to make sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
SET @STR = 'b/bla///';
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM @STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
` SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse('c/string2//'),
PATINDEX('%[^/ ]%',reverse('c/string2//')),
DATALENGTH(reverse('c/string2//'))))`
```

reference:
http://raresql.com/2013/05/20/sql-server-trim-how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-charactersspaces-from-string/